# Modifying an element with javascript after jquery has loaded this element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having an annoying problem. I am trying to modify the header of my web page, which is loaded with the jquery `load` function.

The problem is that header is loaded after I want to modify an element in it. I can not get the sequence right of:

1. load header
2. modify header

Example:

#### Main script

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(function () {$('#includeHeader').load('path to Header.html');});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('aktdatum').innerHTML = 'some text';
        };
    </script>

    <header id="includeHeader"> </header>

    ...
</body>
```

#### Header:

```
<div>
     <ul>
         ...
         <li class="nav_info">
            <div id="aktdatum">
            </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### Error:

> (index):34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

#### Comment:

So, the problem is that when I want to execute this piece of code
`document.getElementById('aktdatum').innerHTML = 'some text'`
the header is not in the body yet.

Apparently the header is inserted after the call. So my question is how to execute the script:
`document.getElementById('aktdatum').innerHTML = 'some text'`
after the header has been loaded.

Obviously `window.onload` doesn't do the job.

Do you have any recommendation?

Thanks, Rok

Comment: `jquery.load()` has a callback you can use. https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Perfect, the callback function does the job. Thank you very much!